# How do I describe an unofficial role on my resume and LinkedIn?

Tags: resume, linkedin, title

I'm a web developer.  At my company my niche is SEO (Search Engine Optimization) and, by extension, site speed.  The position is sort of half-official, as it is understood and agreed upon by my superiors that it is a part of what I do, but it is not part of my job title or anything.

Additionally, SEO can be kind of a scummy thing which puts a bad taste in people's mouths.  I like to think I'm very much on the professional, technical side of SEO and have nothing to do with the scummy stuff.

What's the best way to get across that my specialization/niche is SEO and site speed?  I definitely don't want to lump myself in with the snake oil salesmen which plague the SEO world.  I'm a developer first.  SEO is just a specialty/emphasis.

Ideas:

- Web Developer with an emphasis on SEO and Site Speed
- Developer Specializing in SEO and Site Speed
- Czar of SEO and Site Speed (more cheeky, less professional)

Comment: *"...but it is not part of my job title or anything."* - What is you actual job title ?

Comment: "Developer" appears to be the title on the offer letter I signed for the job.

Comment: So your developer who does web development and have experienced in search optimization.  Honestly, I would expect experience in that area, given your field.

Answer (score 7):

Normally, you'd list your title as Developer and then explain what sorts of things you did in the description of the position.  Something like

> Foo Corp, Developer                                                                                                      2012-present
>
> Full-stack developer that specializes in doing cool thing A and
>          awesome thing B.  Improved site performance by C%.

Answer (score 0):

I would list your title, and then things that you *achieved* in that role. As for the bad taste of SEO's, describing what you did will help, and people who want those skills probably won't care so much. They'll want results more than anything.

e.g.

> Foo Corp, Developer
>
> Using X, Y, Z technologies I:
>   Improved site time to first interactivity by 70% by doing A
>   Improved search engine positioning by ethically optimizing using key words and disclosed partner links
>   Increased customer conversions A% over Y *time* by doing this UI/UX improvement
>   Delivered *important project*  as *role*

Answer (score 0):

**SEO isn't scummy**

SEO isn't the scummy thing anymore, it was 10 years ago. I assume you're not hiding keywords with white font on white background or creating fake websites for link references. Today SEO is more about having a clear website structure and semantic markup.

**Skill**

Just put "SEO" and its tools on your CV as a skill, it will be for your advantage.

Comment: P.S. I don't have SEO skills, therefore I think I'm neutral.

Comment: I agree that SEO has changed for the better over the years, but I'm more concerned with perception than with reality.  A lot of people still picture snake oil salesmen when they think of SEO.

Comment: @BillyPilgrim: The point is that people for whom it's relevant they know the reality, for others you don't need to include it in your CV.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to get across that my specialization/niche is SEO and site speed?

Since SEO feels scummy to you, change the word order (put "site speed" before SEO).

- Developer specializing in Site Speed which optimizes SEO
- Web Developer specializing in Site Speed to produce better SEO results.

FYI, I wouldn't call SEO a 'kind of a scummy thing' (in general) and I'm not sure why you feel that way. Not sure that matters, isn't my world these days.